# GEOJSON Why 3 coordinate system is given, can anyone explain its attribute more briefly

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, web, google-api

While working with maps and using geojson I am facing this problem.

```
geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-149.8072,62.6916,10.1]}
```

Why 3 coordinate system is given, can anyone explain its attribute more briefly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Can you share what problem you are facing? Did you read any documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Can refer this for more detail: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#page-12

3 point system shows lat,long, alt.